# resharding while spark running on kinesis stream

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to process kinesis stream data with spark. I begin my stream with 2 shards. It works fine until I manually split one of my shards. After that my program crashes when new data arrives.

Here is the error message:

```
ERROR ShutdownTask: Application exception.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Application didn't checkpoint at end of shard shardId-000000000001
```

How should I handle the checkpoint of a closed shard in my program?

> EDIT: Adding sample code to this question (which is also highly relevant to me).

Sample code:

```
/* Create a streaming context */
def functionToCreateContext(): StreamingContext = {

  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2) )
  ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDirectory)

  val kinesisStreams = KinesisUtils.createStream(ssc, appName, streamName, endpointUrl,awsRegion,InitialPositionInStream.LATEST,Seconds(1),StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)

  /* Do the processing */
  kinesisStreams.foreachRDD(rdd => ...)

  ssc
}

/* First, recover the context; otherwise, create a new context */
val ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointDirectory,functionToCreateContext _ )

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Please provide a snippet of your code.

Comment: @ErikSchmiegelow I'm actually experiencing the exact same problem as OP, so I took the liberty of adding some sample code to the question.

Comment: The details of my situation were different, so this is not necessarily an answer. But perhaps it is a clue: I had neglected to call `shutdownInput.getCheckpointer.checkpoint()` inside `IRecordProcessor#shutdown`, which caused the above mentioned exception.

Comment: I have filed this bug with spark: [SPARK-18020](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18020)